# Heterogenous lists using type classes

Tags: haskell

I am developing a chat system including chat bots and human chat users.
Every user must be stored in one large list.

Possible implementation using multiple type constructors:

```
data User = Human { humanName :: String, humanAge :: Int }
          | Bot { botName :: String, botAge :: Int }
            deriving (Show, Eq)

users :: [User]
users = [Human "Peter" 31, Bot "Your nice chat bot" 12]
```

To implement the `nextMessage` function taking the last message and returning
a response, I could do this with pattern matching:

```
type Message = String

nextMessage :: User -> Message -> IO Message
nextMessage (Human _ _) msg = putStr ("New Message: " ++ msg ++ " \n> ") >> getLine
nextMessage (Bot _ _) msg = return $ unwords [msg, "is", "an", "interesting", "question!"]
```

But this implementation leads to the problem, that pattern matching wont work anymore if I decide to add any fields to the `Human` or `Bot` constructors later, so I would have to adjust this every time I change the constructors.

That's why I decided to use the option described [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Heterogenous_collections) to implement a heterogenous list using type classes.

This is my approach:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

type Message = String

-- | User wrapper
data SomeUser = forall u. (User u, Show u) => SU u

-- | User type class
class User a where
    -- just getter functions
    getName :: a -> String
    getAge :: a -> Int

    -- function to get the next message, responding to the previous one
    nextMessage :: a -> Message -> IO Message

-- access packed type to implement functions
instance User SomeUser where
    getName (SU u) = getName u
    getAge (SU u) = getAge u
    nextMessage (SU u) = nextMessage u

-- make the wrapper type showable
instance Show SomeUser where
    show (SU u) = show u

-- human chat user
-- gets new messages from user input
data Human = Human { humanName :: String, humanAge :: Int }
             deriving (Show, Eq)

-- automated chat bot
-- calculates new messages
data Bot = Bot { botName :: String, botAge :: Int }
           deriving (Show, Eq)

instance User Human where
    -- implementing the getter functions (annoying)
    getName = humanName
    getAge = humanAge

    -- only function to be implemented differently for different types
    nextMessage human msg = putStr ("New Message: " ++ msg ++ " \n> ") >> getLine

instance User Bot where
    -- implementing the getter functions (annoying)
    getName = botName
    getAge = botAge

    -- only function to be implemented differently for different types
    -- does not need any IO, but has to use it, because of the type declaration
    -- in the type class definition
    nextMessage bot msg = return $ unwords [msg, "is", "an", "interesting", "question!"]

-- list containing every chat user
users :: [SomeUser]
users = [SU (Human "Peter" 31), SU (Bot "Your nice chat bot" 3)]
```

I like this because it seems to be more generic than the first version, **but** for every field I need to add a getter, or if needed even a setter, function to the interface to access the values in the same way no matter whether the object is a `Human` or a `Bot`.

The second issue, related to both implementations, is the type of the `nextMessage` function. Because the `Human` type needs the `IO` monad to get
its answer, every `User`-like type has to do the calculation inside the `IO` monad which implies the calculations to be impure although those of the `Bot` type are perfectly fine, pure code.

**Main questions**:

- How to get rid of the annoying getter / (setter) functions in the second implementation?
- How to handle the need of the `IO` monad for some types?

See the module at work:

```
ghci> getName (head users)
"Peter"
ghci> getName (last users)
"Your nice chat bot"
ghci> nextMessage (head users) "Hey, how are you?"
New Message: Hey, how are you? 
> I'm fine!
"I'm fine!"
ghci> nextMessage (last users) "Hey, how are you?"
"Hey, how are you? is an interesting question!"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original problem

> that pattern matching wont work anymore if I decide to add any fields to the Human or Bot constructors later, so I would have to adjust this every time I change the constructors.

can be easily solved by matching data constructors without their fields:

```
nextMessage :: User -> Message -> IO Message
nextMessage Human{} msg = putStr ("New Message: " ++ msg ++ " \n> ") >> getLine
nextMessage Bot{} msg = return $ msg + "is an interesting question!"
```

In this case changing fields in `Human` or `Bot` won't break `nextMessage`.

You can enable [`NamedFieldPuns`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#ghc-flag--XNamedFieldPuns) extension to get only specified fields :

```
{-# LANGUAGE NamedFieldPuns #-}

nextMessage :: User -> Message -> IO Message
nextMessage Human{humanName} msg = putStr ("New Message: " ++ msg ++ " \n> ") >> getLine
nextMessage Bot{botName} msg = return $ msg + " is an interesting question!"
```

Haskell also [allows](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#ghc-flag--XDisambiguateRecordFields) different datatypes to have common field names, so the code could look like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NamedFieldPuns #-}

data User = Human { name :: String, age :: Int }
          | Bot   { name :: String, age :: Int }
            deriving (Show, Eq)

nextMessage Human{name} msg = putStr ("New Message: " ++ msg ++ " \n> ") >> getLine
nextMessage Bot{name} msg = return $ msg ++ " is an interesting question!"
```

Comment: This is actually quite handy. Do you have any idea for the `IO` monad problem in the `nextMessage` function?

Comment: Without seeing  how `nextMessage` is used, It is not obvious if it worth to split pure code from `IO`.  Mixing pure code and side effects is a bad style, but in your case it is not that much pure code you are mixing.

Comment: Obviously the correct implementation of `nextMessage` for the `Bot` type is way more complex than this simple one-liner, so it is definitely worth to get rid of the unnecessary `IO` monad for the `Bot` type.